# Drupal 6 Search module double ID's

Tags: search

I'm currently busy with a website for a costumer. This website has to be W3C validated. There was a problem on the search page of the site with a double ID:

```
<div class="form-item" id="edit-keys-wrapper">
  <label for="edit-keys">Enter your keywords: </label>
  <div class="container-inline"><div class="form-item" id="edit-keys-wrapper">
  <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="keys" id="edit-keys" size="40" value="" class="form-text" />
</div>
```

The ID: `id="edit-keys-wrapper"` comes up two times! This is not W3C allowed.

I've downloaded and installed a clean Drupal 6.28 to be sure it's not a theme error.

Is there a patch for this "problem"? If not, what is the best option to fix this without ruining core?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can confirm this happens out of the box all the way back to at least 6.25.

You can 'fix' it pretty simply with the following code:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_form') {
    unset($form['basic']['#id']);
  }
}
```

That gives this markup in place of the old:

```
<div class="form-item">
  <label>Enter your keywords: </label>
  <div class="container-inline">
    <div class="form-item" id="edit-keys-wrapper">
      <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="keys" id="edit-keys" size="40" value="book" class="form-text error">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="op" id="edit-submit" value="Search" class="form-submit">
  </div>
</div>
```